# Unable to initialize Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I am trying to set up Mockito 2.22 and have downloaded [`mockito-core-2.22.2.jar`](https://bintray.com/mockito/maven/mockito-development/2.22.2#files/org%2Fmockito%2Fmockito-core%2F2.22.2) and [`byte-buddy-1.9.0.jar`](https://bintray.com/raphw/maven/ByteBuddy/1.9.0#files/net%2Fbytebuddy%2Fbyte-buddy%2F1.9.0) and, in the Netbeans 8.2 project, I have added those two jar files, `JUnit 4.12` and `Hamcrest 1.3` to the test libraries.

When I try to run the MCVE:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class SimpleMockTest {
    public static class A{
        public String value(){ return "A"; }
    }
    @Test
    public void testASimpleMock()
    {
        A mocked = mock( A.class );
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test, I get the error:

```
Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.InstantiatorProvider2 (alternate: interface org.mockito.plugins.InstantiatorProvider)
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:74)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getInstantiator(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:44)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:69)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1895)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1804)
    at com.stackoverflow.test.SimpleMockTest.testASimpleMock(SimpleMockTest.java:13)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.<init>(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:16)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.DefaultMockitoPlugins.create(DefaultMockitoPlugins.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.DefaultMockitoPlugins.getDefaultPlugin(DefaultMockitoPlugins.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:67)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:238)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:226)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:68)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Is there another dependency that I am missing? Or some other configuration/annotiation/setup that needs to be done to fix the error and allow the object to be mocked?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use a buid tool that handles dependencies (i.e.gradle or Maven, as explained in the documentation (https://site.mockito.org/). Here are the **direct** dependencies it would automatically get for you if you used one: https://site.mockito.org/. Of course those dependencies can themselves have other dependencies, etc. etc. Which is one of the reasons we use such build tools.

Comment: @JBNizet I am working on an offline system that will never be connected to the internet. The other internet connected network I use is locked down such that I cannot create a local repository from which to package dependencies. Apart from that, I would love to use that route as it would save me so much hassle.

Comment: I'm talking about a **build** tool. The build tool is not used at runtime. You use it to download the dependencies and buid your app. The app can then be deployed anywhere you want, and doesn't need any internet access. Not to mention that Mockito is typically used to test your code. It isn't used at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JBNizet's suggestion to use Maven led me to [Mockito's maven pom](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/mockito-core-2.23.0.pom) which lists the dependencies as:

- byte-buddy 1.9.0
- byte-buddy-agent 1.9.0
- objenesis 2.6

Downloading [`objenesis`](http://objenesis.org/download.html) and adding it to the project fixed the issue.